# content overlapping fixed navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me why this is happening?

I'm creating website for my university assignment, and I got this problem when I try to create fixed responsive navigation bar. the body content such as  or  will overlap the fixed navbar when I scroll down.

[THIS IS THE EXAMPLE PICTURE OF HOW IT OVERLAPPED THE FIXED BAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMBf2.jpg)

Here is my HTML code:

````
<html lang= "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tanat Resort</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale= 1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo">TANAT RESORT</a>
            <ul class="desktop-list">
                <li class="desktop-menu"><a href="resident.html">Resident</a></li>
                <li class="desktop-menu"><a href="event.html">event</a></li>
                <li class="desktop-menu"><a href="more.html">More..</a></li>
                <li class="desktop-menu" id="book-button"><a href="#" id="book-menu">Book now</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="burger-menu" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <div class="menulogo1"></div>
                    <div class="menulogo2"></div>
                    <div class="menulogo3"></div>
            </a>

            <ul id="responsive-menu">
                <li class="hidden-menu"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-menu"><a href="resident.html">Resident</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-menu"><a href="event.html">event</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-menu"><a href="more.html">More..</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-menu"><a href="more.html">About us</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-menu"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section id="search-bar">
            Search bar here
        </section>

        <article>
            <section class="main-article">
                <h1>Discover the most adventurous resort in the world</h1>
                <h1>Tanat's Resort</h1>
            </section>

            <section class="main-galleries">
                <img class = "banner-img" src="images/beach-top-view.jpg" alt="beach">

                <article class="gallery-articles">
                    <h2>Experience</h2>
                    <p>Beach, ocean, volcano. </p>
                    <a href="#" class="more-buttons">DISCOVER MORE</a>
                </article>
            </section>

            <section class="main-galleries">
                <img class = "banner-img" src="images/bird-s-eye-view-photo-of-cabanas-1456293.jpg" alt="resort view from top">

                <article class="gallery-articles">
                    <h2>Our resident</h2>
                    <p>"Would you like to buy a vowel?" printed on the front. He listens carefully to Mark’s diagnosis. Then he unshoulders his heavy hoe and starts digging.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="more-buttons">DISCOVER MORE</a>
                </article>
            </section>

            <section class="main-galleries">
                <img class = "banner-img" src="images/lava-flowing-1687530.jpg" alt="lava flowing picture">

                <article class="gallery-articles">
                    <h2>Activities</h2>
                    <p>Test 12345</p>
                    <a href="#" class="more-buttons">DISCOVER MORE</a>
                </article>

            </section>

            <article id="slide-galleries">
                <p>Slide Galleries</p>
            </article>

        </article>

        <footer>
            <section>
                <p>Footer</p>
                <p>Footer</p>
                <p>Footer</p>
                <p>Footer</p>
                <p>Footer</p>
            </section>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>```

and CSS code (I only provide the responsive css code)




@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }

    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: white;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-color: grey;
    }

    a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 5px 15px;
    }

    .desktop-menu {
        display: none;
    }


    .burger-menu {
        margin-right: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        top: 33px;
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        list-style: none;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-color: grey;
        display:none;
    }

    .hidden-menu { 
        display: block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
    }

    .hidden-menu:hover { 
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-color: grey;
    }


    /*burger menu*/
    div.menulogo1, div.menulogo2, div.menulogo3 {
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    /*transition from 3 bar to x bar*/

    /*first bar of menu logo*/
    .change .menulogo1 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 3px);
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 3px);
    }

    /*delete second bar*/
    .change .menulogo2 {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    /* third bar rotate*/
    .change .menulogo3 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px)
    }



    /*body part start here*/
    #search-bar {
        margin: 70px 20px 10px;
        background-color: olive;
    }

    .main-article {
        display: none;
    }

    .main-galleries {
        padding: 20px 15px 15px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .main-galleries h2 {
        margin: 10px 0px 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .gallery-articles {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .gallery-articles h2 {
        font-size: 25px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 15px 0px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-color: grey;
    }

    .gallery-articles a {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 40px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        transition: 0.3s;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .gallery-articles a:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .banner-img {
        margin: auto;
        width: 90%;
    }

    #slide-galleries {
        background-color: gold;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: grey;
    }
}
````

Comment: where is example picture? please provide it also so that I can understand your query better

Comment: @OmChaudhary The picture was accidently linked incorrectly, and therefore, you will have to view it by scrolling to the bottom of the code in the answer. Anyways, the image can be viewed at https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMBf2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved your issue. All you have to do is add `z-index: 999` (or any other high number) to your navbar.

Like so:

```
.navbar {
   z-index: 999;
}
```

This allows this to be on top of everything with a `z-index` that is below `999`. You can learn more about the `z-index` property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). I hope this helps!

Comment: @Bareck Thanks, can you accept my answer then, if it works?